# JobRunr and Spring Data JPA: How to update database during job execution?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, transactions, jobrunr

i've implemented an asynchronous job processing using *SpringBoot* and *JobRunr*. To store my data, i use *Spring Data JPA* and the *@Transactional* annotation. However, the status of my entities is not stored in the database **DURING** the job execution, just **AFTER** the job execution has been finished. Since the job needs about 5 minutes to finish, i want to update my entities during the job execution, so the user can inspect the changing progress via GUI.

My Code looks like the following (simplified job call):

```
        @Job(name = "Translation job with id '%0'", retries = 2)
        @Transactional
        public void executeTranslationJob(String orderId, File translationOrderContent) throws IOException {
            TranslationOrder translationOrder = this.translationOrderRepository.findById(orderId).get();

            //I want to update the entity's status here
            translationOrder.setTranslationOrderStatus(TranslationOrderStatus.PROCESSING);
            Iterators.partition(this.translationSegmentRepository.findByTranslatedValueAndOrderId(null, orderId).iterator(), 100).forEachRemaining(segments -> {
                machineTranslator.translateSegments(notTranslatedSegments);

                //I want to update the entity here after each iteration of 100 segments processed
                this.orderStatisticsService.updateTranslationProgress(translationOrder, notTranslatedSegments);
            });
            this.updateOrderStatus(translationOrder);
        }
```

Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "translation_order")
@Data
public class TranslationOrder implements Persistable<String> {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private String id;

    @Column(name = "order_status")
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private TranslationOrderStatus translationOrderStatus;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "statistic_id", referencedColumnName = "id", foreignKey=@ForeignKey(name="FK_order_statistic"))
    private OrderStatistic orderStatistic;
}
```

And the repository:

```
@Repository
public interface TranslationOrderRepository extends JpaRepository<TranslationOrder, String> {

    //custom findby-methods
}
```

How is it possible to update entities during job execution (and so during method execution)?

I tried to call save() or saveAndFlush() after each update statement, but that does not help.

Comment: Well, you put the entire Job into one transaction that will get commited when the job is done. Move the updates to a seperate service.